# Preserve Ransack search between multiple endpoints/controller functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a model that updates its results through ajax calls to and endpoint that I named `/model/filter`, and I'm trying to incorporate search into the mix. I've added Ransack and it works just fine on the index (if I just search), but I want it to also work when I apply a filter.

In my controller function I have replaced `@models = Model.scoped` with

```
def filter
  @search = Model.search(params[:q])
  @models = @search.result.scoped

  # apply other filters...
end
```

However, when an ajax call executes this function, I get back a result that doesn't use the search terms.

I either want to ensure that `params[:q]` reaches `/model/filter` in the same state as it was in when `/model/index` loaded (a JS solution), or I want to be able to access the same `@search` object when I call `filter` (a Ruby solution).

Am I way off base here, or is this something that's easy to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution after some more searching.

In `/model/index`, I added `Rails.cache.write("q",params[:q])`.

Then, in `/model/filter`, I added `params[:q] = Rails.cache.read("q")` before I called `@search = Model.search(params[:q])`

Comment: Good. I'm designing a web-site that'll require a search bar to be always visible, so.. I was thinking about placing the Ransack (controller) action in the application controller. Did you do it this way? It'd be really helpful to me If you could provide more details about how you did it. Could you please give me the link where you found your solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use session. Super simple. In your controller for search:

```
@your_model = YourModel.where(some_filter_criteria_if_necessary: "something")
@q = @your_model.search(params[:q] ? params[:q] : session[:search])
@your_model = @q.result(distinct: true).page params[:page]
if params[:q]
  session[:search] = params[:q]
end
```

This way session will be overridden only when there is new criteria provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is my session-based solution with application controller. Different params stored for different controllers and actions

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :store_and_set_search_params

  # store params of ransack into session and set @search_params variable
  # controller_name and action_name have different definition for rails < 4.1
  def store_and_set_search_params
    session[:q] = session[:q].deep_merge({controller_name => { action_name => params[:q] }}) if params[:q]
    @search_params = session.try(:[],:q).try(:[], controller_name).try(:[], action_name)
  end
end
```

Action:

```
def index
  @search = Item.search(@search_params)
  @items = @search.result
end
```